# Prove that $\bar z = z^2$ for $z \in \Bbb C$ and find for what complex numbers is satisfied

Tags: complex-numbers

We know that:

$\bar z = a-bi$

and

$z^2 = (a+bi)^2 = a^2 + 2abi - b^2$

So I think there are two ways to solve it, to set a counter-example or to develop equality, but I’m not sure.

How can I find those complex numbers that satisfy equality?

Comment: Perhaps equating real and imaginary parts and solving the resulting equations?

Comment: this will work out better if you say $z=re^{i\theta}$ instead of $z=a+ib$.

Comment: Setting the complex parts equal immediately gets you down to two cases: $b=0$ or $a=-1/2$.  Then set the real parts equal to pin down the other coordinate in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $z=0$ is a trivial solution. One proceeds to solve for nonzero $z$.

$$\overline{z}=z^2\Rightarrow \frac{\overline{z}}z=z,$$ which implies that $z$ has norm $1$. It follows that $\overline{z}=\frac 1 z,$ hence $$\frac 1 z=z^2\Rightarrow z^3=1.$$ The rest is obvious.

Comment: I solved it in a similar way, though I took the modulus on both sides instead of your first step. I did not include my solution because it is too close to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using exponential form, let $z = re^{i\theta} \implies \bar z = re^{-i\theta}$

You're given $re^{-i\theta} = r^2e^{2i\theta}$ which implies $r = r^2$ so $r = 0$ or $r = 1$.

For $r = 1$, we have $e^{3i\theta} = 1 = e^{2k\pi i}, k \in \mathbb Z$ so $\theta = \frac{2k\pi}3, k \in \mathbb Z$, which correspond to the cube roots of one.

So $z = 0, 1, \omega, \omega^2$

Answer (score 0):

First, for $b=0$, there are solutions $z=0+0i$ and $z=1+0i$. Next, assume $a,b \neq 0$. For the equation $a-bi = a^2-b^2+2abi$ to be true, we must have that the real and imaginary parts coincide, i.e. we must have $a=a^2-b^2$ and $-b=2ab$.
From $-b=2ab$, we get that $a= -\frac12$. Plugging this into the equation $a=a^2-b^2$, we get that $b= \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Hence, the equation $\bar{z}=z^2$ holds only for $z = -\frac12 \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Hope this helps!

Comment: You forgot $z=1+0i$ when you said “it is clear...”

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You're right, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: there is a number other than $z=0+0i$ such that $\overline z=z^2$, namely, $z=1+0i$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Okay, it should be fine now. Sorry for the confusion.